# Trying to parse a string to two seperate strings based on case

Tags: python, html, string, uppercase, lowercase

I'm currently working on a python bot which retrieves information from a meta block on an HTML page. I get the content of the meta block, and now I am stuck on trying to parse it to two different strings.

An example of the content would be:

```
Lowercase Words WITH UPPERCASE CONTAINING 2 AND ALSO ', AND MANY MORE CHARACTERS
```

So far I have:

```
lowercase = ' '.join(w for w in content.split() if (not w.isupper()) and (not w.isdigit()))
uppercase = ' '.join(w for w in content.split() if (w.isupper() or w.isdigit()))
```

where the uppercase string is meant to contain everything that isn't the words "Lowercase" or "Words"

I have not been able to find much help with this sort of issue, and was wondering if anyone would know of a trick or work around? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

s = "Lowercase Words WITH UPPERCASE CONTAINING 2 AND ALSO ', AND MANY MORE CHARACTERS"
match = re.match(r"(([^\s]*[a-z]+[^\s]*\s+)+)([^a-z]+)", s)
if match:
    lowercase = match.group(1)
    uppercase = match.group(3)
```

This will match a single line string beginning with an arbitrary number of words of which each must contain at least one lower case letter(`a-z`). Note, that camel-case is also recognized as a lower case string (e.g. `"LowerCase"`). The second part will then match the rest of the string which must not contain any lower case letters.

Let's try to understand the regexp now:

1. We want to match lower case words, so we write: `[a-z]+`
   But this will only match words that are completely made up from lower-case letters - we want to allow other characters as well and match the word as lower case if it contains *at least one* lower case character. `[^\s]` will match any character that is not a white-space (word boundary). We combine both patterns like this: `[^\s]*[a-z]+[^\s]*`.
   This matches any number of non-whitespace characters (even zero) followed by lower-case characters and then followed by any sequence of non-whitespace characters again. So this basically means, we match any sequence that does not contain white-space and at least one lower-case letter.
   Now we make a sequence of such words, delimited by whitespace: `([^\s]*[a-z]+[^\s]*\s+)+`
2. Matching the upper case part is pretty straight-forward, because we only need to match everything (including whitespace) that is not a lower-case character: `[^a-z]+`

To make matches of both patterns available through groups, we wrap 'em up in braces again:
lowercase: `(([^\s]*[a-z]+[^\s]*\s+)+)`
uppercase: `([^a-z]+)`

Perhaps you need to adjust the pattern further, to suit your needs, but I believe this should be a good starting point...

Comment: Thank you very much, Alexander! This post worked excellently, with an amazingly simple solution and beautifully crafted explanation. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> from string import punctuation as punc
def ispunc(strs):
    return all(x in punc for x in strs)
... 
>>> strs = "Lowercase Words WITH UPPERCASE CONTAINING 2 AND ALSO ', AND MANY MORE CHARACTERS"
>>> ' '.join(w for w in strs.split() if (w.isupper() or w.isdigit() or ispunc(w)))           
"WITH UPPERCASE CONTAINING 2 AND ALSO ', AND MANY MORE CHARACTERS"

>>> ' '.join(w for w in strs.split() if (not w.isupper()) and (not w.isdigit() and not ispunc(w)))           
'Lowercase Words'
>>>
```